# Why pom.xml was not recognized successfully

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

The color of words in the pom.xml are all white and when i click the element of xml,it says "Cannot find declaration to go to".
[image]

Comment: Please check that `*.pom` is added under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types | Recognized File Types | XML` Also try to delete the `disabled_plugins.txt` file from the configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory while the IDE is closed.

Comment: *.pom is right there. Disabled_plufins.txt is empty.

Comment: Please contact IntelliJ support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide the IDE logs. (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried all the suggestions others told me before,it still didn't work. Today I cut the pom.xml to other directory and then I cut it back. The pom.xml was recognized correctly.I cant believe it ！I think it is IDEA bug!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it "In the Project tool window, right-click the project folder and select New | Module. Alternatively, from the main menu, select File| New | Module to open the New Module wizard." https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_add_module

Comment: I added a new module and its default pom.xml was recognized correctly.So?

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate Caches -> cross out "Clear file system cache and Local history and then "Invalidate Restart"

Comment: i did as you said.it didn't work